# Call method on ES6 class instance of React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm brand new to React and I'm using it in combination with ES6 classes. I have a class that inherits from `React.Component` and renders DOM based on a single property in its `state`. Here's how that looks:

```
class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { state: 'isHidden' };

  showTrying() {
    this.setState({ state: 'isTrying' });
  }

  hideAll() {
    this.setState({ state: 'isHidden' });
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.state.state) {

    case 'isHidden':
      return null;

    case 'isTrying':
      // Returns a bunch of DOM elements
  }
}
```

In a parent class, that is not a React component (I'm attempting to migrate existing code that uses no framework), I want to:

1. Create an instance of `LoadingScreen`
2. Call `React.render` to insert it in the DOM
3. Call methods such as `hide` or `showTrying` on that instance to update its state

I've tried:

```
this.loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen();
React.render(this.loadingScreen, mountNode); // React invalid component error

// Later on...
this.loadingScreen.showTrying();
```

And also tried:

```
this.loadingScreen = React.render(React.createElement("LoadingScreen"), mountNode);

// Later on...
this.loadingScreen.showTrying(); // Undefined is not a function
```

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach was close.

The first argument to [`React.createElement`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) can either be a string (div, span, etc.) or a subclass of `React.Component`. In your case, the first argument should be `LoadingScreen`.

```
this.loadingScreen = React.render(React.createElement(LoadingScreen), mountNode);

this.loadingScreen.showTrying();
```

Comment: Wow I was even closer than I thought. Thanks Morhaus!

Answer (score 3):

It would be more common that you'd set a property on the `LoadingScreen` component instance to control the visibility of the internal representation rather than adjusting the state via a function call on the object instance.

```
class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    switch (this.props.mode) {
        case 'isHidden':
          return null;
        case 'isTrying':
          // Returns a bunch of DOM elements
    }
  }
}

LoadingScreen.propTypes = { 
    mode: React.PropTypes.string
};
LoadingScreen.defaultProps = { 
    mode: 'isTrying'
};
```

Then, from the parent, you'd do something like this for example:

```
var currentMode = "isTrying";
React.render(<LoadingScreen mode={ currentMode } />, mountNode);
```

Or, another pattern is that the parent container/component uses the value of the property (I've called `mode`) to just not create and render the `LoadingScreen` component at all.

If the `LoadingScreen` needs to, you could copy the `property` value into local state as you've done.

Comment: Also good advice, although I've kept mode as a string as there are actually more than just two (trying to keep it simple for the example). It sounds like you're advocating creating a new component instance each time via a separate call to render. I can see why that makes sense, but in the case of migrating this code, I need to keep the instance around.

Comment: It's unusual in React that you'd actually need to keep the instance around. In fact, that's really not typical at all (and an anti-pattern). React components should be created on demand and instantiated from state/properties. If this is new code, (which it must be), You should be able to affect the behavior of the component using standard React patterns without calling a method directly on the component instance. I switched the code to passing in a var for example.

Comment: Also -- the boolean change was accidental in my code. I was thinking "visibility" as I wrote that and had forgotten you'd used strings.